# "Falling back to non-recursive partition" sphinx 4

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4

I trained my Acoustic model and received acceptable accurate rate (85%) over a small data (10 Vietnamese words). but when I integrate this model in to Transcriber sample (packaged with Sphinx 4) and try to transcribe a word, which is in the 10 above words, I received a list of "Falling back to non-recursive partition". I need it to output a word instead.

[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?58bfo4ai44yd3xk) is my project.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> acceptable accurate rate (85%) over a small data (10 Vietnamese words).

This error rate is too high, you need to work on improvement of this result. Accuracy on 10 words must be over 95%. See CMUSphinx troubleshooting section in acoustic model training tutorial for more information.

> received a list of "Falling back to non-recursive partition".

This error is a sign of a problem in your input data.

In latest code this error should not be displayed, please also update to a latest version.

Comment: too see "Falling back to non-recursive partition" printed to the console - but I doubt I have zero energy region in my inputs - how did you tell this is the problem in his case,  and how can I tell my problem?

Comment: He provided the link on the audio and I opened it and checked. If you want to get help on your issues you need to provide an example including the audio you are trying to decode.